# This text changer works fine but i need to to loop continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arrNames = [
            '<span class="highlight">For All Joinery & Building Requirements.</span>',
            '<span class="highlight">No Job Too Small, No VAT Charges, Free Estimates!</span>',
            '<span class="highlight">Hardwood, Softwood & UPVC Windows, Doors, Porches & Conservatories.</span>',
            '<span class="highlight">Extensions, UPVC Soffits & Facias, Roof & Renovation Work & Loft Conversions.</span>',
            '<span class="highlight">Kitchens & Bathrooms designed & Installed with a full tiling service available.</span>',
            '<span class="highlight">For your free quote, call us today!/span>',
        ];

            $.each(arrNames, function(i, val) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.quotes').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $(this).html(val).fadeIn("slow");
                    });
                }, i * 8000);

            });
```

How would I repeat this function so it keeps looping, it plays its once through perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setInterval` along with of `setTimeout`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eWQn/3/)**

```
$.each(arrNames, function(i, val) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.quotes').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).html(val).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            }, i * 8000);
        });
setInterval(function(){   
$.each(arrNames, function(i, val) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.quotes').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).html(val).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            }, i * 8000);
        });
},48000);
```

Comment: That just makes the first part flash!

Comment: Would be great if you can create the fiddle.

Comment: @Josh: I have updated the answer. Check fiddle for demo.